# Bootstrap Brand Logo - Resizing when overhanging

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Currently I am required to overhang the logo over the navbar as per what my boss wants. He is happy with the look of it and so am I, but the thing I can't seem to figure out is when I resize the browser or view of the website on my mobile, the logo doesn't resize and also stops the drop-down navbar from working.

Any help is appreciated, guys. I tried everything before asking on here. This is my first question ever on StackOverflow.

Thank you in advance.

```css
#logo {
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .navbar-brand img {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="img-responsive navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#" title="Barcelona 226 Center Exclusive - Official site">
  <img src="logo.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Barcelona226">
</a>
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve? The "logo" image is too big for mobile, you are going to render the text in the image unreadable on mobile. 
What you can do on mobile is something like @media (max-width:480px) { #logo { width: 75%; } #logo img { width: 100%; } }

Comment: Using % can lead to problems if you don't have a position:relative parent with fixed height. Try to declare the logo dimension in px